# Can I leave a EU country (Germany) with an expired visa but with a another already being created?

Tags: european-union, germany, visa

The case of my friend is: she lives in Germany, has a visa that is already expired, and she already paid for a new one and it is being produced, but the waiting time is 2+ month. She can't wait anymore and wants to go home (Ukraine) for several months.

The plan is: when the new visa will come we will send her the new one via a package.

The main issue I see is the going out of the country. Could there be some problems, fees, or restrictions for her situation?

I would appreciate every bit of information or any link that you could throw at me. Thanks!

Comment: Does she have some form of written confirmation that the renewal has been approved (letter approved until xx, new residence card will be sent)? If yes, she should take that with her. If not, she should ask for one.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, she has one!

Comment: That then will be proof a) she as not overstayed b) that she can reenter as a resident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Germany does not require an exit visa to leave the country. She is free to return to Ukraine without the new visa, but she will of course need it to re-enter Germany in the future.

It is best to present evidence that she hasn't overstayed her previous visa to avoid any issues, as this will be checked when leaving the country.

Comment: Exit checks will still be done and having proof of no overstay is advised.

Comment: Adding to Mark: overstay might be a reason to deny future Visas

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this, thanks!